# Is the taskId globally unique in a Redisson distributed scheduler service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redisson

So I could not find any confirmation [in the official documentation](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-Distributed-services#931-distributed-executor-service-overview) on the uniqueness of the taskId returned after scheduling a task. Is the taskId globally unique (between all the Redisson nodes) or is it just unique for a single Redisson node? I am pretty sure it is globally unique, otherwise it would mean that if I want to cancel a task I have to cancel the task on the same Redisson node it was scheduled on. To me this would seem like a huge limitation (if it was true).

Answer (score 0):

Task id is globally unique. It's a 128-bit random value